# Why am I getting a runtime error eventhough it runs perfectly on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm

I was solving [this problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MAIN72/); it runs perfectly on my eclipse but giving run time error on spoj platform ...anyone can please tell me the error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main22 {
    /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean[][] arr=new boolean[100][10000];
        int[]arry=new int[100];
        int sum,total,i,j,test,no;
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        test = inp.nextInt();
        while(test--!=0)
        {
            sum = 0;
            no = inp.nextInt();
            for(i=1;i<=no;i++)
            {
                arry[i]=inp.nextInt();
                sum+=arry[i];
            }
            for(i=0;i<=no;i++)
            {
                arr[i][0]=true;
            }
                for(i=1;i<=sum;i++)
            {
                arr[0][i]=false;
            }
            for(i=1;i<=no;i++)
            {
                for(j=1;j<=sum;j++)
                {
                    if(arry[i]>j)
                    arr[i][j]=arr[i-1][j];
                    else
                    {
                        arr[i][j]=((arr[i-1][j])||(arr[i-1][j-arry[i]]));
                    }
                }
            }
            total = 0;
            for(j=1;j<=sum;j++)
            {
                if((arr[no][j]))
                {
                total+=j;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(total);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: *Always* specify what the error is when you describe a situation where you run into an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know on **SPOJ** main class should be called Main while in your code it is **main22**

Have a look at http://www.spoj.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=43